# Good speedtest results, but web pages don't load

Tags: browser, internet-connection, website, ping

I have strange connection problems. Ping and download times are good -
speedtest.net showed ping 65ms and download 2.17Mbps. Torrent is working well, giving me up to 300MBps.

Webpages are loading very poorly though. They are timing out each time - I'd have to refresh 4-5 times to get any simple page to load. It has been happening consistently for the last few days. Same with different browsers on different machines (same network), Windows and Linux. There is no proxy in the browser.

Is there any setting in Windows or in a browser that I can change to help this?

Some background: I live on this island in Thailand, where internet connection is through radio to another island and than to mainland - it's very weather dependent, but generally OK. As I mentioned, ping is good.

Any input is very appreciated.

Comment: Is your browser configured to use a proxy?

Comment: @David Schwartz No - no proxy

Comment: Did you check? Or do you mean it's not supposed to be configured to use one?

Comment: It's not supposed to and it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Speedtest.nets ping and download test results are from a server that is close to you. The websites you are trying to access may not be at the same location as the speedtest.net server.
Torrents again download from multiple seeders close to you.

Try manually selecting a server in the US (farthest from you) to get an estimate of ping.

Finally does this happen with all websites or some or a particular one. It is a particular website that is slow, it could simply be that it is overwhelmed with requests and nothing to do with your connection or settings.

You can try switching to using Google Public DNS, see if that helps.
https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using

Comment: This happens with all websites irregardless of their ping. Say google pings around 80, superuser.com pings 400-500. Both behave roughly the same. Same for a lot of others.

Comment: As to the Google Public DNS: if I continuously ping their IP 8.8.8.8, I always get good ping turnaround, but a lot of pings don't return. In a good time of the day 8 out of 10 return, in a bad - 2 out of 10 or so. So it's not just my providers DNS, it's something else, and it's probably nothing to do with timeouts. I guess I'll have to deal with the Thai ISP.